# Disable darkmode for textColor edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles, android-darkmode, android-spannable

disabled the dark mode for the application with

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

But in the input in the case, when you need to remove Span, the textСolor is reset to white and becomes invisible.

Пример:
text: Editable?
start: Int

```
    val spans = text?.getSpans(start, start, ForegroundColorSpan::class.java)
    spans?.forEach { span ->
        text.removeSpan(span)
    }
```

if you change styles textColorPrimary to red, for example, the color does not change. But if you make it in the direction of dark , then this color is inverted to light red